# Execute node.js child process in browser by browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, browserify

I am using browserify to get node.js to run on the browser. I want to execute a child process so I am doing something like this in the index.js

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 //I'm just checking the node version installed, you can do your own    process here

var ls =exec('node -v', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
if (error !== null) {
console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
});
```

A  bundle.js is generated using browserify command

```
browserify index.js -o bundle.js -d
```

Also included the bundle.js in html

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But in the browser's console I am getting as

```
"exec is not a function"
```

Node version is v0.12.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

browserify does NOT run node.js in the browser.

> Browserify lets you require('modules') in the browser.

so your code is nice and tidy.
But, there is no `child_process`, `net` or `fs`.

Once again, you are NOT running node on the browser.

P.S. There are modules that are implementations of net and fs for the browser though such as `browserify-fs` etc.

Comment: Hi @Rahat , What can I do here to include the child_process here

Comment: Nothing. Also, no `node -v` because there's no node. Although, I do not know what your end goal is, `webworkers` are sort of like child processes on the browser. You can spawn processes with them despite the browser running JavaScript on a single thread.

Comment: so you are saying that there is no way to execute a child process , I wanted to run a command by using it

Comment: No there is no way to create a `child_process` and execute a `command` from a javascript file in the browser and there would and should never be a way. (If it were possible, what's stopping someone running `rm -rf *` on your computer). What you CAN do is, have a button on the frontend and run node.js code on the backend where you spawn a child_process and run any command you want when that said button is pressed.

Comment: what if you are building for electron or NW.js?